# Activity with webView Loading every time

Tags: java, android, html, android-activity

In my app i have button when it clicked the app goes to another activity with webView to show HTML table 
The issue here is when i press back and return to the same activity the webView load agin and it take while how can i prevent it from loading over and over agin and will turnning the HTML table to listview will make it loade faster if yes . How ?

Comment: your question is not much cleared.. see example if u got idea from my answer accept it...

Answer (score 0):

**You can Preserving the state of an Android WebView on screen orientation change or activity is paused.**

If you’ve tried to use a WebView inside your app, you know that the standard behavior on screen orientation change is not satisfactory in most cases because the full state of the WebView is not preserved or similarly when your activity is pause same situation WebView will change their sate.

**possible implementation to keep the full state of the WebView**
here complete tutorial and code is given you can get idea from this **[code&tutorial](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/)**

Comment: thank you so much . but can you tell me is it useful to convert HTML table to listView or other type to make the app load faster ???!!

Comment: their are a lot of 
[tutorial-1](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jsoup-listview-images-texts-html-tables-tutorial/) [tutorial-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305310/android-how-to-parse-html-table-into-listview) check these...